# How to Sign a .jar file with my Apple Developer ID

Tags: java, code-signing, executable-jar, osx-gatekeeper

I have a java executable `jar` file that I need to be signed with my Apple Developer ID. I don’t intend to distribute it through the app store. I will be distributing the app directly to customers through my website. I’m not intending to bypass Gatekeeper. `Signing the app` with my `developer ID` is what will satisfy Gatekeeper when customers install the app and thus avoid a security prompt that I am an "**Unidentified Developer**".

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

From apple.stackexchange.com:

> [Signed binary being warned as signed by unknown developer on
>   OSx](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249971/signed-binary-being-warned-as-signed-by-unknown-developer-on-osx)
>
> It appears the security settings of the computer in **System
>   Preferences → Security & Privacy** are set to Allow apps downloaded
>   from: App Store as shown in the error message.
>
> Regardless of how your application is signed, if it's not distributed
>   through the App Store, Gatekeeper will show that message. To allow all
>   other signed apps, the setting needs to be changed to **App Store and
>   identified developers**

See also:

> [How to sign Java applet with Apple Developer ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192382/how-to-sign-java-applet-with-apple-developer-id)
>
> Oh, there is no way to do it =( Java applets cannot participate in the
>   Developer ID program. The Apple's answer is here
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/12210534/1068878.

Answer (score 1):

Use `appbundler` tools from oracle sdk (if you are using JDK version 8 or+, else download it manually). I could do similar stuff by following steps mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html).

Comment: It's my understanding that the only thing you can do to keep Gatekeeper from complaining is to change system settings :(  The Oracle link also has this nifty command that's worth trying: `spctl --assess --verbose=4 --type execute ExampleApp.app`