# Deploying JAR files on Mac

Tags: macos, javafx

I have written a JavaFX program with NetBeans on Windows. When I *zip* it for deployment on a Mac, after the Mac unzips the ".jar", it tells the user that "the software is not safe". If the user continues despite the warning, all is well. How can I get around this deterrent for potential end users?

DCP Setup produces another JAR.

Mac to install the program without suggesting it is unsafe.

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate of: [How to Sign a .jar file with my Apple Developer ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53313548/how-to-sign-a-jar-file-with-my-apple-developer-id), though I have never tried that and don't know 100% that it would actually fix your issue.

Comment: Another approach is to create a "self-contained application", which bundles the java runtime and your app together into an installable native OS app, and have that signed with an Apple developer ID (possibly with distribution through the apple App Store) so that the [apple gatekeeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatekeeper_(macOS)) allows it without prompting.  A guide for some of the steps for this are in a [java packager with jdk11 blog post](https://medium.com/@adam_carroll/java-packager-with-jdk11-31b3d620f4a8), a long guide and maybe not comprehensive.