# Java jar file error in MAC OS. Possible reasons?

Tags: java, macos, java-web-start, jnlp

I am downloading a java web start app from the web, and using the jnlp file to run it in my MAC OS. But the application does not start and gives me the following error.

[image]

Now, I have read a lot about this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767394/unidentified-developer-for-java-web-start-application-on-os-x) and how to sign the application [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958130/how-to-sign-dynamic-jnlp-files-for-osx-and-gatekeeper/17222479#17222479) and other places. Plus I have read about the security update which started this error [here](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202746).

All these articles and answers give the impression that this error can only occur due to the application being from an unidentified developer.

I just wanted to confirm whether that is the case, or can there be some other reason behind this, like expired code signing cert, or a self signed cert?

If there can be multiple reasons for this error, how to find out which one it is?

Comment: Heres a comment that doesn't really answer your question at all: If you trust this application and would like to run it you can allow apps like this to run if you have admin access to you computer.  Go to System Preferences -> Security and Privacy --> General Tab --> "Allow apps downloaded from" and select the "anywhere" option.  This should be done at your own risk.

Comment: @ChrisStarling, well, I know this.. And btw, I don't see this particular option you mentioned. "Allow app downloaded from".. All I see is "open anyway"..

Comment: *"I just wanted to confirm whether that is the case, or can there be some other reason behind this, like expired code signing cert, or a self signed cert?"* A 'self signed cert' **is** from a developer that the JVM cannot confirm is an identified developer. Just as the developer could tell you they are 'Joe Blogs', so could I create a home made certificate that identifies me as the same (and so could anybody else with a Java SDK). Sun/Oracle used to allow self signed code with a warning, but decided that wasn't secure enough. Now only code signing certificates from a CA are good enough.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, So this error could also come if the jar was signed with a self signed certificate?

Comment: Yes............